# R: selecting the names of the 2 columns with the highest colSums in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
df = 
A B C D
1 4 0 8
0 6 0 9
0 5 0 6
1 2 0 9
```

I want to obtain a vector with the names of the two columns with the highest `colSum`:

```
"B" "D"
```

So far I have tried:

```
List_names_TOP2 <- str(sort(colSums(df), 
                 decreasing = TRUE)[1:2])
```

but I get an error. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `named` `vector` from `colSums` ('v1') to `order` in decreasing and subset the first two `names` with `head` and `sort` those column names

```
v1 <-  colSums(df)
sort(head(names(v1)[order(-v1)], 2))
#[1] "B" "D"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(4L, 6L, 5L, 2L), 
    C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), D = c(8L, 9L, 6L, 9L)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```